# Apple Health Kit Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5 "Authorization not determined"

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit, hksamplequery

I have determined authorization before actually trying to save any data or do anything with it. The error is happening at the moment of query:

```
HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:foodType 
predicate:predicate 
limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit 
sortDescriptors:nil 
resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error){ ... }
```

Yes, I have read apple documentation that says:

> Attempts to save data before permission has been requested fail with a
>   HKErrorAuthorizationNotDetermined error.

But I do request permissions before I try to ask for data (I see the list with all data types (in the code - dataTypesToRead / Write)).
Did anybody have this type of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found out the problem. In the data types when identifying which types of data can the app read and write I had the wrong type for Sleep analysis.

Wrong:

```
HKCategoryType *sleepType = [HKSampleType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleep];
```

Right:

```
HKCategoryType *sleepType = [HKSampleType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis];
```